# Generate Entity domain model from classes

Tags: entity-framework

I write my domain classes first. Entity framework allows you to generate code and create a database and also generate domain classes. What about generating the entity diagram from the already written domain and then generating the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Build classes, then generate a DB, then make a UML model (**not** an entity model) from your classes (code-first)
2. Build a model, generate classes, generate a DB (model-first)

But there's nothing built in that precisely matches the flow in your question.

Comment: How do I generate a DB from classes?

Comment: Code-first does that by default. Write your classes, follow the standard code-first tutorials, and your DB will be generated at runtime.